# Error in Cloud composer with data build tool (dbt) path ['name']: 'jaffle_shop' does not match '^[^\\d\\W]\\w*$'

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, dbt

I am testing a deployment of dbt within Cloud composer. On my local machine (Ubuntu 20.04) I have got success in running the dbt models with airflow. When running on Google Cloud composer I get the following error

```
{subprocess.py:74} INFO - Output:
{subprocess.py:78} INFO - Running with dbt=0.21.0
{subprocess.py:78} INFO - Encountered an error while reading the project:
{subprocess.py:78} INFO -   ERROR: Runtime Error
{subprocess.py:78} INFO -   at path ['name']: 'jaffle_shop' does not match '^[^\\d\\W]\\w*$'
{subprocess.py:78} INFO - 
{subprocess.py:78} INFO - Error encountered in /home/airflow/gcs/dags/dbt_project.yml
{subprocess.py:78} INFO - Encountered an error:
{subprocess.py:78} INFO - Runtime Error
{subprocess.py:78} INFO -   Could not run dbt
{subprocess.py:82} INFO - Command exited with return code 2
{taskinstance.py:1503} ERROR - Task failed with exception
```

We are using a BashOperator to run dbt models in Airflow.
Initially had some problems with dependencies but they were solved.
Using a standard `dbt_project.yml` file with a single model just to test how this works.
Another way is to use Docker but we need try if this works.

**Edit**

**Versions**

dbt: 0.21.0

cloud-composer: 1.17.1

airflow: 2.1.2

**Pypi Packages**
airflow-dbt: 0.4.0

dbt: 0.21.0

jsonschema: 3.1 (Added this as Pypi was throwing an error about the version

I really appreciate if anyone can help

Pete

Comment: Same issue here: jsonschema==3.1.0, Jinja2==2.11.3, dbt-bigquery. dbt version: 1.1.0, python version: 3.8.12.  Removing the name entirely results in the expected 'Required "name" field not present in project', but no version of name seems to pass the regex.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `jsonschema` dependency.  Version 3.1.0 does not work, while versions 3.1.1 and 3.2.0 will work--and should also work within Composer's dependency requirements.

There looks to have been an issue with switching to `js-regex` for the jsonschema folks in 3.1.0, which caused them to revert back to regular `re` in 3.1.1.

There are some details [here](https://github.com/python-jsonschema/jsonschema/blob/main/CHANGELOG.rst#v311), and a couple of related issues described [here](https://github.com/python-jsonschema/jsonschema/issues/611) and [here](https://github.com/python-jsonschema/jsonschema/issues/612).

In general, it would be much nicer if Cloud Composer supported virtual environments to avoid this entire dependency-collision mess, but apparently Google does not support that approach.